# Understanding stripos offset?

Tags: php, stripos

Let's say I've a small array () :

```
    $array = array(
        'Pantin',
        'Paris',
        'Paris',
        'Puhahaa',
        'Ptdr',
        'Roumanie',
        'Rlolo'
    );
```

What I want to do? 
Simply get all words that start with the 'r' letter

```
$dataLen = sizeof($array);
$results = array();

for ($i = 0; $i < $dataLen && count($array) < 10; $i++) {
    if (stripos($array[$i], 'r', 0)) { // 

        array_push($results, $array[$i]); 
    }
}

print_r($results); // Output : Array ( [0] => Paris [1] => Paris [2] => Ptdr )
```

I can't understand.. I put 0 as the offset, but it gives me words that start with the P letter and that "contain" the R letter.

Comment: You're asking it to "start search at offset 0", not "stop searching after offset 0". Try `in_array($array[$i][0], array('R', 'r'))` instead.

Comment: @DCoder Yes thank you, I saw this on internet ! But why === 0 isn't it supposed to be FALSE? Why should I put it outside the function? Can you please explain me this, I'll accept your answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Zero is the default value, so these things are equivalent;

```
stripos($array[$i], 'r', 0)
stripos($array[$i], 'r') // Same
```

That is, they start at position 0 and try to find the letter `r` or `R`. If it is not on position 0, they check the second letter, then the third letter etc.

Stripos returns the position of the found letter. For *Paris* is returns 2, for *Rlolo* it returns 0. If it is not found it returns false.

By default, 0 and false are both interpreted as false. So if the first letter is `R`, `stripos` returns 0 and the if statement is not executed. To solve this, use this code:

```
if (stripos($array[$i], 'r') !== false) { ... }
```

If you want to check just the first letter and not the subsequent letters, you can do something like this:

```
$word = $array[$i];
$firstLetter = $word[0];
if ($firstLetter == 'r' || $firstLetter == 'R') { ... }
```

Comment: or simply `stripos($array[$i], 'r') === 0`

Comment: Clear and simple! Thank you very much!

Comment: @Yoshi: that's probably slower than just checking the first symbol directly. Not significantly, but still.

Answer (score 1):

Another method would be using array_filter with a callback.

```
$results = array_filter($array, function($var) {
    return strtolower($var[0]) == 'r';
});
```

(Of course you could also use `return stripos($var, 'r') === 0;`)

Comment: Thank you for this alternative.